Why do many mosfet models exclude Cds ​ in parasitic capacitances?
Why do many models of MOSFET parasitic capacitances not include \$ C_{ds} \$?

(the image taken from this site)
In integrated circuits, MOS transistors usually have four terminals. If we consider parasitic capacitances between any two terminals, we would have \$\binom{4}{2} = 6
 \$ parasitic capacitors. However, many models I found online omit \$ C_{ds} \$ and include only 5 capacitors.
I have seen \$ C_{ds} \$ included in power transistor models, as it is important for power converters. However, it is not as commonly included in models at the IC design level. Why is this the case?

What is substrate usually connected to, particularly in power transistors? How might this fact be used to simplify the model?

@TimWilliams In discrete power transistors, the substrate is usually connected to the source terminal, Csb does not exist and other capacitors can be combined. However, my question is, why is Cds not usually considered.

Cds is the series combination of Cdb and Csb. In power MOSFETs, S and B are shorted, so Csb goes away and Cdb becomes Cds.

@SteKulov That is new to me. I thought there was a physical capacitor between the drain and source.

I think that is the correct explanation. If any two of you want to make it an answer, I'll accept it.

The capacitance model in your middle image is correct for monolithic MOSFETs, which are used in integrated circuit design.  There are three gate capacitances (\$C_{GD}\$, \$C_{GB}\$, \$C_{GS}\$), and then two capacitances for the PN junctions from the drain & source terminals to the substrate (\$C_{DB}\$, \$C_{SB}\$).  There is no separate capacitance between drain and source because to get from one terminal to the other, you have to go directly through the body.  Therefore, the equivalent capacitance between drain and source would be the series combination of \$C_{DB}\$ & \$C_{SB}\$ (assuming the body is floating).
It's a similar concept to pin-to-pin capacitances for pins on the same row of an IC.  If you have pins 3, 4, and 5 in a row, then there is a capacitance from 3-to-4 and 4-to-5.  The capacitance from 3-to-5 would be the series combination of 3-to-4 and 4-to-5 (again, assuming pin 4 is high-Z).  If it's symmetrical (i.e. 3-to-4 equals 4-to-5), then the capacitance of 3-to-5 would be half of 3-to-4 (or half of 4-to-5).
In power MOSFETs (discrete MOSFETs), the body terminal is connected to the source, so \$C_{SB}\$ goes away, \$C_{GB}\$ merges into \$C_{GS}\$, and \$C_{DB}\$ becomes \$C_{DS}\$.  It's in these devices where you will see \$C_{DS}\$ defined on its own.
